# What is likely to cause very slow file copy over 10Gb NICs?

Tags: linux, networking, performance, copy, 10gbit

Copying data across my local network is extremely slow. The network in question is 10Gbe only. That is everything on the 10.0.2.0 subnet is 10Gbe and every device/switch is on the same VLAN with jumbo packets enabled (9000).

I need to transfer 16TB of data, at least twice between two Linux Supermicro servers (both RAID 6 arrays on LSI cards) so I would like it to be as efficient as possible.

The best I've achieved so far is 9min 14sec to transfer 49G. The odd thing is, to rule out as much as possible, I connected the servers directly and NFS mounted the receiving filesystem and this did not improve things much. 8mins 46sec.

A local copy from SSD to target disk array of the same 49Gb of data took 1min 14sec.

With this direct connection, iperf3 reports;

```
iperf3 -c 10.0.2.18
Connecting to host 10.0.2.18, port 5201
[  5] local 10.0.2.16 port 57632 connected to 10.0.2.18 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr  Cwnd
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec  1.15 GBytes  9.90 Gbits/sec    0   2.85 MBytes
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec  1.15 GBytes  9.90 Gbits/sec    0   3.00 MBytes
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec  1.15 GBytes  9.89 Gbits/sec    0   3.00 MBytes
[  5]   3.00-4.00   sec  1.15 GBytes  9.89 Gbits/sec    0   3.00 MBytes
[  5]   4.00-5.00   sec  1.15 GBytes  9.90 Gbits/sec    0   3.00 MBytes
[  5]   5.00-6.00   sec  1.15 GBytes  9.90 Gbits/sec    0   3.00 MBytes
[  5]   6.00-7.00   sec  1.15 GBytes  9.89 Gbits/sec    0   3.00 MBytes
[  5]   7.00-8.00   sec  1.15 GBytes  9.90 Gbits/sec    0   3.16 MBytes
[  5]   8.00-9.00   sec  1.15 GBytes  9.89 Gbits/sec    0   3.16 MBytes
[  5]   9.00-10.00  sec  1.15 GBytes  9.90 Gbits/sec    0   3.16 MBytes
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec  11.5 GBytes  9.90 Gbits/sec    0             sender
[  5]   0.00-10.04  sec  11.5 GBytes  9.85 Gbits/sec                  receiver

iperf Done.
```

which looks good to me.

So why does an NFS copy;

```
root@kitkat:~/.ssh# time cp -a /mnt/vmfs/CO_ictDC /mnt/smicro1/TEST

real    8m46.683s
user    0m0.089s
sys     1m27.369s
```

take so long bearing in mind a local copy on the target server;

```
root@esxidev:~# time cp -a ./CO_ictDC /mnt/raid6/TEST/

real    1m14.693s
user    0m0.307s
sys     1m1.827s
```

Anybody got any pointers?

Edited to answer some questions in comments below. Not sure how else to do it.

@LPChip, the copy has definitely finished as I've checked the files.

@harrymc, connected via optic cable and sfp+ between each servers nic.

@spiff, rsync is slower, as is scp. Not by much but it is slower. Tried ftp too, that gets around 100Mb/s.
The only nics connected were the 10Gbe nics and both were connected to the same TP-Link TL-SX3008F which has no 1Gbe or RJ45 ports.

Comment: Its likely that the copy appears finished, but is still happening in the background from cache, and that this caching is not possible over lan.

Comment: How exactly have you directly connected the servers ?

Comment: Try with a purpose-built file transfer tool like `rsync` instead of pairing `cp` with a remote filesystem protocol like NFS. A common problem with copy performance on remote filesystem protocols is that the code doing the copying might be assuming the low latency of a local disk instead of the relatively high latency of a network read. So if `cp` reads a chunk of data at a time from the remote filesystem, then waits for the read to complete, then writes it locally, and then reads the next chunk, that's fine on a local filesystem, but over a network, the network goes idle in between reads.

Comment: Also, are you sure the 10Gb path is the only path between these devices? I note that your current copy speed is around 750-800Mbps, which hints that you might be limited to a 1Gbps link somewhere. If both of these devices also have 1Gbps NICs by which they can reach each other, and you're mounting by hostname not IP address, you might be mounting over a 1Gbps path instead of your 10Gbps path.

Comment: Sneaker-net is a thing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sneaker-net . If the SSD is eight-or-so times faster, use it. An employer for whom I worked regularly transferred data by shipping an HDD using one-day mail -- and effective throughput far exceeded their internet speed.